python pytest fixture, how to mock function that is imported within a function
I am trying to write a pytest fixtures for existing code that will create an testapp but it fails because the lookup function has some dependencies.  I like to mock the lookup function. How do i properly mock the lookup function so i can bring up the test fixture without failure.
excerpt of edited file: app/service/__init__.py.
def create_app(test_config):
    app = FastAPI()
    app.state.config = config
    from . import example, lookup
    app.include_router(example.router)
    app.include_router(lookup.router)
    return app

excerpt of my fails attempts. (edited) :  app/test/conftest.py
from app.service import create_app

@pytest.fixture
def app(settings):
    mock_lookup = mock.MagicMock(return_value={'name': 'test_vc'})
    with mock.patch('lookup', mock_lookup):
        return create_app()

location of lookup file:   app/service/lookup.py
I tried the above with different paths such as app.service.lookup or .lookup, and lookup.route) with no success.  It still tries to import the lookup function which has a lot of dependencies.

The app() and app.services namespace in conftest.py is conflict.
